# Nitrogen molecule vs carbon-carbon triple bond stability

Tags: bond, stability

Why does the triple bond in the nitrogen molecule convey *stability*, whereas a triple bond between carbon atoms conveys *instability*?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Note that — like everywhere on the internet — all-caps words are perceived as shouting. Rather, use markdown such as italics `\*like this\*` (*like this*) to emphasise.

Comment: What do you mean by stability? In what way are alkynes unstable?

Comment: Why, alkynes are unstable in many ways. Consider positive $\rm{\Delta_fH}$, for starters. Acetylene is _explosive_, and diacetylene even more so. That being said, though, the $\rm{C{\equiv}C}$ triple bond is quite strong, almost as strong as $\rm{N{\equiv}N}$.

Comment: I guess reactivity would be better word here.

Answer (score -3):

You might already know that elements like to follow the octet rule, which means that atoms tend to combine in a way that each atom can have eight valence electrons. Nitrogen can exist diatomically because through the triple bonds, each nitrogen will have one lone pair and three shared pairs. As seen in the picture, each nitrogen satisfies the octet rule.

[image]

Carbon, on the other hand, cannot satisfy the octet rule diatomically. Since carbon has one less valence electron than nitrogen, a triple bond would not work because the carbon does not have enough electrons to bond and satisfy the octet rule. It would leave each carbon atom with three bonded pairs of electrons and only one lone electron, giving each atom a configuration of only seven electrons per atom, not eight. Sorry I don't have a picture of a triple carbon bond. Hope this answers your question though!

Comment: It doesn’t really, because there are a high number of $\ce{C#C}$ bonds known, e.g. in acetylene $\ce{H-C#C-H}$.

Comment: that's true, but in that case,  the hydrogen bonds with the lone electron in carbon, to give carbon a full valence shell.  C2H4 like you mentioned above a stable molecule. @Jan

Comment: If that's your response to my comment you missed the question and I must give you $-1$.